# If there is opportunity to use SQLite in Sencha Touch 2 Apps?

Tags: sqlite, sencha-touch-2

I would like to make Sencha Touch 2 application and  I need to use client-side data storage. So if there is a way to use SQLite Database or same alternative ?
My application need to work if user has no internet access and user is able to do CRUD on the data. 
When the device establish internet connection, the application should synchronize client-side database (SQLite) with server-side DB.

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 opportunities i think.

The first is working with WebSQL. 
It's like a SQL Database. But it's deprecated in favor of indexedDb (which is currently not available for mobile browsers).

There is a Plugin for WebSQL and Sencha Touch 2. https://github.com/grgur/Ext.data.proxy.WebSQL

The second opportunity ist working with LocalStorage.
You can CRUD your data direct with a store and the 'localstorage' proxy.
But it is no SQLite Database, however i think you can use it for your problem.

Sencha Docs: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage

Comment: you are saying that the SQL database can't be used in native packaging?

Comment: No, you can use it in native packaging. Native packaging is just like a web container in a native application. But deprecated features could may be removed in later releases of the mobile browser and then the Application won't work anymore.

Comment: But Sencha should provide us with database instead limited local storage which is ugly...

Comment: Well, i think this is not a problem of Sencha, the current mobile web browsers don't support many variants to store data.

Comment: But there could perhaps exist a Phonegap plugin, which provides the feature to store the data in the native database of a device.

Comment: is there any way to use phonegap plugin with sencha?

Comment: Phonegap is a native packager for web applications. You can pack your Sencha Touch application with phonegap to a native iOS or Android application. Then you can use the phonegap plugins inside Sencha

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of Sencha Touch (2.1) has built-in support for Web SQL via the Ext.data.proxy.Sql class.

This provides official support for Web SQL. However, it has virtually no documentation and is quite painful to use. A good starting point is here: http://druckit.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/using-the-sencha-touch-2-1-sql-proxy/

I have been using it myself for a project and have found that it doesn't provide errors when there is a problem. As an example, I had an issue where I misspelled a sort-by declaration (which are apparently required but not documented as such) and it stopped working. No errors were displayed. After about 5 hours, I figured out the issue and it started working again.

It is painful but it will get the job done for full DB local storage.